# disable asp.net mvc dropdown using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Below is my jquery code and my ASP>NET mvc razor code. Razor code is for dropdown list. I want to disable the dropdown when the labelCount variables value is 0. The values comes to 0 but the dropdown is not getting disabled.

```
if (labelCount == 0) {
    $("#AndOrSelection").attr("disabled", "disabled");
}

@Html.DropDownList("AndOrSelection", new List<SelectListItem>()
{ 
    new SelectListItem { Text = "And", Value = "And" },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "Or", Value = "Or" }
}, "Select criteria")
```

Comment: Your code works fine. Is the script in a `document.ready()` block? Are you getting any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @StephenMuecke : thanks.. the code wasn't inside document.ready(). Thanks ..

Comment: You can also simplify you code a bit - `@Html.DropDownList("AndOrSelection", new SelectList(new List<string>() { "And", "Or" }), "Select criteria")`

Answer (score 1):

The best place to put your jQuery code is near the closing body tag (as best practices recommend)

Following will work

```
 @Html.DropDownList("AndOrSelection", new List<SelectListItem>()
 { 
   new SelectListItem { Text = "And", Value = "And" },
   new SelectListItem { Text = "Or", Value = "Or" }
 }, "Select criteria")

<script>
if (labelCount == 0) {
$("#AndOrSelection").attr("disabled", "disabled");
}
</script>
</body>
```